# How to add link tag for image_src for facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to add link tag with rel image_src in head tag using javascript so that i can get image in facebook during sharing link of this page.

```
var linkTag='<link rel="image_src" href="https://graph.facebook.com/picture" />';

var headHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
headHTML    += linkTag;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = headHTML;
```

Above code is adding link in head tag perfectly but problem is that facebook is not getting this picture when I share the link of this page.

When i add this Link tag in head Manually then facebook perfectly picks this image but when i add this Link tag using javascript then facebook does not pick the image.

Why is this behaving so?

How can i fix this issue? please help.

Comment: Maybe the problem is you must to execute at start, not when click on the share button. Don't know if the Facebook robot can execute javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what your `<link>` tag should deliver as those tags are usually meant for style sheets. If so, your tag should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://graph.facebook.com/picture/mycss.css">
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp to find out what you can pass to `rel`

So, you should go like:

```
var linkTag = document.createElement('link'),
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

linkTag.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
linkTag.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
linkTag.setAttribute('href', 'https://graph.facebook.com/picture/mycss.css');

head.appendChild(linkTag);
```

If this is not exactly what you need,... it will at least give you a hint on how to do it properly, as the innerHTML doesn't work on the .

In your case (as you wrote it) it would then be:

```
var linkTag = document.createElement('link'),
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

linkTag.setAttribute('rel', 'image_src');
linkTag.setAttribute('href', 'https://graph.facebook.com/picture');

head.appendChild(linkTag);
```

Good luck!

Comment: actually <link rel="image_src" href="https://graph.facebook.com/picture" /> is used to provide facebook an image to use as thumbnail for the link we share.

And the method you used is almost doing the same work as mine. But in this way facebook does not capture the thumbnail we are trying to provide.

Comment: could it be that you're missing the image in the path?

https_://graph.facebook.com/picture/`myImage.jpg`